# How to use internal networks with Traefik 2.x?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to setup a simple Nextcloud Stack with docker-compose and Traefik.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nextcloud-database:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: nextcloud-database
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - $PWD/db:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - db.env
    networks:
      - backend
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: '12m'
        max-file: '5'
      driver: json-file

  nextcloud-redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: nextcloud-redis
    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend

  nextcloud-cron:
    image: nextcloud:latest
    container_name: nextcloud-cron
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - $PWD/cloud:/var/www/html
    entrypoint: /cron.sh
    networks:
      - backend

  nextcloud-app:
    image: nextcloud:latest
    container_name: nextcloud-app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - $PWD/config:/var/www/html/config
      - $PWD/cloud:/var/www/html
      - $PWD/apps:/var/www/html/apps
      - $PWD/data:/var/www/html/data
    environment:
      - NEXTCLOUD_DATA_DIR=/var/www/html/data
      - MYSQL_HOST=nextcloud-database
    env_file:
      - db.env
    depends_on:
      - nextcloud-database
      - nextcloud-redis
      - nextcloud-cron
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.rule=Host(`nextcloud.blablubb.de`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.middlewares=nextcloud-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-secure.rule=Host(`nextcloud.blablubb.de`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-secure.service=nextcloud"
      - "traefik.http.services.nextcloud.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
    networks:
      - proxy
      - backend
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: '12m'
        max-file: '5'
      driver: json-file

networks:
  proxy: # this is the network provided by traefik
    external: true
  backend:
    external: false
```

and the db.env

```
MYSQL_PASSWORD="waff"
MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="waff"
```

The Nextcloud instance is reachable via the domain nextcloud.blablubb.de. 
So my question:
What's needed that my nextcloud-docker container can communicate with each other?
I thought it's handled through the backend network, but I've always error message, f.e. nextcloud-mysql isn't reachable.

Without Treafik this setup is working fine.

Thank you guys.

Comment: why is your backend network marked as not external?

Comment: Why it should be external for internal communication?

Comment: I know -- but where is your backend network defined?

Comment: At the end of the docker compose yml

Comment: I tried that with my docker-compose and it threw an error about an undefined network. What if you simple renamed backend to default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want two containers to be able to communicate with each other you need to have an overlay network and add both of the containers to the same network like

```
docker network create --driver=overlay --subnet=10.0.15.0/24  --attachable traefik
```

```
    networks:
      - backend
```

which is the case in your docker-compose file, here is an example for doing this

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true

volumes:
  db_data:

services:

  proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    command:
      - '--providers.docker=true'
      - '--entryPoints.web.address=:80'
      - '--providers.providersThrottleDuration=2s'
      - '--providers.docker.watch=true'
      - '--providers.docker.swarmMode=true'
      - '--providers.docker.swarmModeRefreshSeconds=15s'
      - '--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false'
      - '--providers.docker.defaultRule=Host("local.me")'
      - '--accessLog.bufferingSize=0'
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        delay: 10s
        order: start-first
        parallelism: 1
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        'max-size': '10m'
        'max-file': '5'
    networks:
      - traefik

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --general-log=1 --general-log-file=/var/log/mysql/general-log.log
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        delay: 10s
        order: start-first
        parallelism: 1
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        'max-size': '10m'
        'max-file': '5'
    networks:
      - traefik
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dummy
      MYSQL_DATABASE: rails_blog_production

  rails_blog_web:
    image: wshihadeh/rails_blog:demo-v1
    command: 'web'
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.services.blog.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
        - traefik.http.routers.blog.rule=Host(`blog.local.me`)
        - traefik.http.routers.blog.service=blog
        - traefik.http.routers.blog.entrypoints=web
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        delay: 10s
        order: start-first
        parallelism: 1
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        'max-size': '10m'
        'max-file': '5'
    networks:
      - traefik
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mysql2://root:dummy@mysql/rails_blog_production
      RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: 'true'
```

one thing that is missing in your configurations is the linking between the services. For instance, you are providing the MySQL host in the application server but the port is missing.

Comment: Hi Al, thanks for your answer. It's not needed to give the port of MySQL. I don't get that network issue with overlay. If you can see here https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/blob/master/.examples/docker-compose/insecure/mariadb-cron-redis/apache/docker-compose.yml there is no network specified but they can communicate. Is that a Traefik thing?

Comment: in the example, you provided the network definition is not there. as a result, the network will. be created when your run `docker-compose up -d` and all containers will be in the same network. On the other hand, you defined the `backend` network.  as a result, I think that you need to create the network before starting the service. You can verify if the networks are created by running `docker network ls` and check if the containerins are in the same network by `docker inspect container_id`

Comment: can you explain also which service is not reaching which?

Comment: I cannot access the MariaDB, Redis and Cron container from the app, I'll try your variant.

Comment: after a deeper look at the docker-compose file, I noticed that you are assigning the containers to a network called "backend". While this network is not defined in the file at least not with the exact name.  The network ("backend") defined at the end of the file will be created with a dynamic name (something like "${folder}_backend" ). to fix this you can add a name to the network. like `backend:
    external: false
    name: "backend"
`

Comment: I started the stack on my machine and it seems that you can reach the services from the app. `➜  stackoverflow/access/testd   docker exec -it nextcloud-app bash                                                                                                                                                                   (2.6.3)
root@b4c8dd4623e5:/var/www/html# telnet nextcloud-redis 6379
Trying 172.20.0.2...
Connected to nextcloud-redis.
Escape character is '^]'.
`